# How to resize Chrome browser window with an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser

I am making a chrome extension and wanted to add an option to resize the browser window.
I know I can't resize the window with normal JS.(`window.resizeTo(600, 600);` etc. won't work)

But with extension it's possible. For example with [this tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh/) you can resize the window. Problem is that I don't know how.

Also seems [possible](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp) to open a new tab with desired sizes but it won't open a normal window but a tab.(Like ads)

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Here's a [repo](https://github.com/grahamlicence/chrome-resize/) for that. Tested ✅

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer:

We need 2 js files. background.js and main.js(content js file, name can be anything).

main.js doesn't have access to extension apis, tabs, background stuff etc. So we will send a message to background.js from our main.js file and get that message in background.js file and execute what we want.

*main.js:*

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  {
    action: "resizeWindow",
  },
  function (createdWindow) {
    console.log("Window Resize");
  }
);
```

background.js:

```
  //Windows resize
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request && request.action === "resizeWindow") {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (window) {
      var updateInfo = {
        width: 1200,
        height: 710,
      };
      (updateInfo.state = "normal"), chrome.windows.update(window.id, updateInfo);
    });
  }
});
```

Note that we need `updateInfo.state = "normal"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the window API  for chrome extensions

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(wind) {
alert(wind.id);
var maxWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
var maxHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
var updateInfo = {
    left: 0, //change those to whatever you like 
    top: 0,
    width: maxWidth,
    height: maxHeight
};
chrome.windows.update(wind.id, updateInfo);});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I doing it wrong? Nothing happens. I have the tab permission, added it to scripts(background.js) bu doesn't do anything.

Comment: `
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request && request.action === "reSizeWindow") {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (wind) {
      alert(wind.id);
      var maxWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
      var maxHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
      var updateInfo = {
        left: 0, //change those to whatever you like
        top: 0,
        width: maxWidth,
        height: maxHeight,
      };
      chrome.windows.update(wind.id, updateInfo);
    });
  }
});`

Comment: You can try it on the chrome console of the extension step by step